# Corresponding letters in string

Tags: vb.net

```
   Dim charArray() As Char = randomWord.ToCharArray     'Splits the selected words into individuals strings in a array

    Letter1.Text = charArray(0)                          ' Changes each label into its corresponding character from array
    Letter2.Text = charArray(1)                          '*
    Letter3.Text = charArray(2)                          '*
    Letter4.Text = charArray(3)                          '*
    Letter5.Text = charArray(4)                          '*

    If randomWord.Contains(answer) Then                  'if random word contains the users input
        MessageBox.Show("You are correct!")
        Correctcounter()
        winorLoss = "won"
        highScore()
        Userinput()
```

I have setup 5 labels , which each correspond to a character from a 5 letter word. I am looking for a way for , if the users input(which is the  variable
         answer ) is present in the variable randomWord , the corresponding word in the variable randomWord is set as the corresponding Letter.text. Therfore if the users input is "j" which is present in the word "juicy" , the first label changes to represent a "J". Sorry for the poor formatting.

Comment: `String.IndexOf` will tell you where a certain letter or substring is, but in that code isnt J already showing in Letter1?

Comment: I forgot to add the variable randomWord which would contain "juicy" , cycles through a array and picks the word , so the word might not be juicy it could "hello" or "goodbye" for example" therefore it would show j for that however it wouldn't work with other words .

Comment: What happens if the pool contains JUICY and BANJO? DO you show it in 2 places?  `String.IndexOf` will tell you IF it contains a letter and if so, where

Comment: Yes but if i use string.indexOf , how will i translate that to the labels . I would get the location of the letter in the word but how would i code it so the it appears on the corresponding label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show us the data type of answer. Below code assumes `answer` and `randomWord` are of type `String`.

```
Dim i As Integer
Const COUNT_LIMIT As Integer = 5


If randomWord.Contains(answer) Then
    Dim charArray() As Char = randomWord.ToCharArray
    answer = answer

    Try
        For i = 1 To COUNT_LIMIT
            Dim lbl As Label = Me.Controls("Letter" & i.ToString)
            If Char.ToUpperInvariant(charArray(i - 1)) = Char.ToUpperInvariant(answer) Then
                lbl.Text = charArray(i - 1)
                'Exit For 'Use exit for if you are sure randomWord has no repeating character
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Problem with label Letter" & i.ToString & " -- " & ex.Message)
    End Try

    MessageBox.Show("You are correct!")
    Correctcounter()
    winorLoss = "won"
    highScore()
    Userinput()
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong! Try again.")
End If
```